# coverting grey8 (8bit) image into a rgb888(24bit) image

Tags: c#, image, .net-4.5

my problem is when is take a 8bit greyscaled image and convert it into an 24bit rgb24bpp my image gets zoomed in and the colorscale get mixed up( see [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Mjg0.png)). 
My plan is to display a GigE-Cam with my program through a client-server implementation. Therfore i need it the picture to get grayscaled because of daterate issues, but i only get this wrongly sized and collored picture. This happens only if i covert them into the myImage/myImageFormat. My problem is that i need the picture for measurements afterwards.

The code i use to convert the image is as follows:

```
public myImage(Bitmap bmp, myImageFormat format)
    {
        if (bmp == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bmp");
        }

        this.Height = bmp.Height;
        this.Width = bmp.Width;
        this.Format = format;

        // copy bmp matrix without padding to rgb or grey array     
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        //if (format == myImageFormat.Grey8)
        //{ return; }
        //else
        //{
            int factor = 3;
            if (format == myImageFormat.Grey8)
            {
                factor = 1;

                // save grey scale palette
                m_colorPaletteColorData = new Color[bmp.Palette.Entries.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Palette.Entries.Length; i++)
                {
                    m_colorPaletteColorData[i] = bmp.Palette.Entries[i];
                }
                //return;
            }
            else if (format == myImageFormat.Rgb888
                && bmp.PixelFormat == PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed)
            {
                // convert all type of bitmaps to 24-Bit bitmaps by using GDI+
                Bitmap bmp24 = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
                bmp24.SetResolution(bmp.HorizontalResolution, bmp.VerticalResolution); // prevent resolution conversion
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp24))
                {
                    g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel; // prevent DPI conversion
                    g.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
                }
                bmp = bmp24;
            }

            BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat); // LOCKED

            int bytes = bmp.Height * bmp.Width * factor;
            int byteIndex = 0;
            m_imageData = new byte[bytes];
            unsafe
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < bmpData.Height; y++)
                {
                    byte* row = (byte*)bmpData.Scan0 + (y * bmpData.Stride);
                    for (int x = 0; x < bmpData.Width; x++)
                    {
                        m_imageData[byteIndex] = row[x * factor];
                        byteIndex++;

                        if (format == myImageFormat.Rgb888)
                        {
                            m_imageData[byteIndex] = row[x * factor + 1];
                            byteIndex++;
                            m_imageData[byteIndex] = row[x * factor + 2];
                            byteIndex++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData); // UNLOCKED
        //}
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// returns a 8bppGrey or 24bppRgb Bitmap
    /// </summary>
    public Bitmap ToBitmap()
    {
        if (m_imageData == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Internal image data does not exist!");
        }

        PixelFormat pixelFormat;
        int factor = 3;
        if (this.Format == myImageFormat.Grey8)
        {
            pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed;
            factor = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb;
        }

        m_bmp = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height, pixelFormat);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
        BitmapData bmpData = m_bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, pixelFormat); // LOCKED

        int counter = 0;
        unsafe
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < bmpData.Height; y++)
            {
                byte* row = (byte*)bmpData.Scan0 + (y * bmpData.Stride);
                for (int x = 0; x < bmpData.Width; x++)
                {
                    byte color = m_imageData[counter];

                    row[x * factor] = color;
                    counter++;

                    if (this.Format == myImageFormat.Rgb888)
                    {
                        row[x * factor + 1] = m_imageData[counter];
                        counter++;
                        row[x * factor + 2] = m_imageData[counter];
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // copy original grayscale color palette, otherwise it will be a 8bit RGB bitmap
        if (this.Format == myImageFormat.Grey8)
        {
            ColorPalette palette = m_bmp.Palette;
            Color[] entries = palette.Entries;
            if (m_colorPaletteColorData.Length >= entries.Length)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < entries.Length; i++)
                {
                    entries[i] = m_colorPaletteColorData[i];
                }
            }
            m_bmp.Palette = palette;
        }

        m_bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData); // UNLOCKED            
        return m_bmp;
    }
```

Can anyone help me on this problem?

[The Grey8 image converted into an RGB24](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Mjg0.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you pass in a 24-bit bitmap to be converted to 8-bit gray, you won't have a valid source palette to copy, since 24-bit formats aren't indexed.  So, when you save the palette into `m_colorPaletteColorData[]` from the 24-bit source image (in your constructor) and then set it on the 8-bit gray image (in ToBitmap()), what does that palette actually contain?  In the constructor, when your source is 24-bit (and therefore has no valid palette), you need to create a new gray-scale palette rather than try to copy it out of a non-indexed image.

Another lesser point, when converting in both directions (8 to 24, 24 to 8), you assign the bytes from one image to the other directly; so, if one is intended to be a palettized 8-bit image, and the other is a 24-bit image, you are assigning a palette index as each of the R, G, and B values of the color component, or assigning one color component as the index.

This should work (sort of) if-and-only-if the palette is guaranteed to be a linear gradient where each index matches the shade of gray-scale, but palette-based images rarely use a perfectly-organized palette, so this is a dangerous assumption.  To make this work properly, you should really translate the 8-bit index values into the Color values from your palette before assigning to a 24-bit image, and look up the closest match in your color palette from the 24-bit value when assigning to an 8-bit gray image.

Comment: Thanks, i solved my problem. I was sending and 24-bit image as 8bit-format so my converter only read out the blue channel. Therefore my image gets disturbed. Now - respecting the `PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed` and the `PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb` i can use my images as intended. Thanks!!